# Prüfung in or Prüfung <genitive>?

Tags: usage

Attempting to translate:

> United States Robots guaranteed their passing the test of actual performance on an asteroid.

> Die Vereinigte-Staaten-Roboter hat garantiert, dass sie **die Prüfung in der** eigentlichen Leistung auf einem Asteroiden bestehen würden.

but was corrected to:

> Die Vereinigte-Staaten-Roboter hat garantiert, dass sie **die Prüfung der** eigentlichen Leistung auf einem Asteroiden bestehen würden.

While the majority of examples in DWDS agree with the correction, I did find this counterexample:

> Archiv der Gegenwart, Bd. 51, 01.01.1981, S. 24123 [ff.]. Zit. n. CD-ROM-Ausgabe 2001.
> Die polnischen und die sowjetischen Soldaten haben in den gemeinsamen Manövern **die Prüfung in der** Beherrschung der Kampftechnik bestanden.

Does valid usage vary or is there a rationale for one usage or the other?

Comment: Heißt die Firma nicht US Robotics? Firmennamen werden nicht übersetzt. Meine Übersetzung wäre "US Robotics garantiert, dass sie die eigentliche Leistungsprüfung auf einem Asteroiden bestehen würden"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

*Prüfung in* is used with e.g. school subjects or other areas of competence:

> Morgen haben wir eine Prüfung in Mathe.

*Prüfung + <genitive>* is used when something specific is actually tested:

> Die Prüfung der Feuermelder wurde anstandslos abgeschlossen.

The example with the combat technique is borderline, I think both would be valid. You could either consider "Beherrschung der Kampftechnik" a subject area or the actual thing that is being evaluated.

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Pr%C3%BCfung) does not explicitly mention this distinction, but you can see *Prüfung + <genitive>* examples under meaning "1. Das Prüfen" and one *Prüfung in [Russisch]* under meaning "2. Verfahren, bei dem jmds. Kenntnisse [...] festgestellt werden sollen".

It appears that "test" in English works similarly.

Comment: Based upon these criteria, I would have to say then, that the original correction was incorrect, because it is with regard to performance on asteroids in general, not the particular performance on a particular asteroid. Would you agree? Seems to me there can be many instances subject to interpretation.

Comment: I'm missing the larger context, what kind of test, what kind of performance etc. But it appears to me that it is the performance itself that is being assessed, so I would agree with the correction.

Comment: That's the problem. The English provides no further context. It is the performance. But isn't a test in mathematics also a test of performance in mathematics or performance of work done in mathematics? And similarly for any academic subject matter? So isn't a test of performance of work on an asteroid also a test of work done on an asteroid? I do not see how one can say that one is specific and the other not.

Comment: Just like in English, the way you just used it: "Test **in** mathematics." "Test **of** performance in mathematics." is the same as "Prüfung **in** Mathe." and "Prüfung **der** Mathefähigkeiten." (*der* is plural genitive here).

Comment: That is clear. I appreciate the thoroughness of your response.